# How to hide default popup of Quick Action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have created one Component from which I'm creating new record, using force:createRecord

The new record creation page is opening perfectly on click of Quick Action but one new blank model is also showing up on top of that page.
I'm not able to figure out how to hide this popup.

The screen[image] of Popup:

Here is my code:
Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
      <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.createRecord}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
   ({
       createRecord: function(component, event, helper) {
          var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
          createRecordEvent.setParams({
             "entityApiName": "custom_obj__c",
              "defaultFieldValues": {
            'Name' : 'Abc'
            }
          });
          createRecordEvent.fire();
$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
       }
    })
```

Comment: Question, why don't you just create a new "Create Record" quick action? Is there more logic than what we can see?

Comment: Basically I wanted to have a list view button from where I need to prepopulate some value

Comment: Regular quick actions allow you to set default values for fields...

Comment: but I won't be able to use Quick Action in list view button

Comment: You should fire the closeQuickAction event before you fire the createRecordEvent.

Answer (score 5):

Basically you need fire closeQuickAction event after createRecord event to close quick action window. Add below code after firing createRecord event.

```
    var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
    dismissActionPanel.fire();
```

Comment: I already tried it. it is actually closing the new record creation model not the blank model, which is coming on top of the record creation model.

Comment: Plz share your code

Comment: I have modified my code.

Comment: Same thing happened to me when using this code, the answer from Remy Chen and Raul Kasaundhan does work. My best guess firing the event closes the most recently opened quick action window. Using the timeout helps ensure that all windows are open before it fires.

Answer (score 2):

please try the following codes.

```
window.setTimeout(
    $A.getCallback(function() {
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    }), 1000
);
var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
createRecordEvent.setParams({
    "entityApiName": "custom_obj__c",
    "defaultFieldValues": {
        'Name' : 'Abc'
    }
});
createRecordEvent.fire();
```

and let me know whether this works for you. Thanks.

Comment: It is automatically closing the blank model, but users can still see this blank model for some seconds

Comment: Put the time from 1000 to 10 or something else. There is no way to eliminate the start up of blank. Or you can add spinner in the blank popup.

Comment: even giving time as 1, I can see that popup

Comment: You might need to use spinner in the blank popup. You can't make it disappear at the beginning because your new creation is created from that Action. I believe the way you want to implement is impossible.

Comment: After testing, this is the only suggested approach that seems to work. The delay on setTimeout doesn't seem to matter (tested as low as 1/1000th second). For some reason 100/1000 seems to work the best for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think is not Working on direct using for  Onload. It's work when you set the timeout On Load and call dismiss quick action it's Work.

   ```
   doinit : function(component, event, helper) {

       window.setTimeout(
           $A.getCallback(function() {
               $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();

           }),100
       );

       var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
       var newEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
       newEvent.setParams({
           componentDef: "c:Navigate",
           componentAttributes: {
               sNavigateComVal1 :recordId
           }
       });
       newEvent.fire();
   }
   ```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [answer]. Right now, this doesn't look like an answer to me, but rather a similar question. Please consider asking your own question (and linking back to this one, if it helps provide context), and gather up as much information and detail as you can.

Comment: @DerekF I don't think that's correct, this is the same answer another user provided and is functional, Maybe suggest some edits to the language to make it more clear but its not a bad answer.

Answer (score -2):

I posted a solution to this on the developer forums accessible via the link below, worked perfectly to hide the box, box wont appear at all. and there wont be backdrop also.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MVx8QAG

> ```
> <aura:component>
>    <aura:html tag="style">
>         .slds-modal {
>         visibility: hidden;
>         display: none;
>         }
>         .slds-backdrop{
>         display: none;
>         
>         }        
>   </aura:html>
>   <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{!c.doInit }"/>
> </aura:component>
> ```
>
> Aura Controller J:
>
> ```js
>  doInit: > function (component, event, helper) {
>    $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
>          
>    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
>    evt.setParams({
>      componentDef : "c:methodName",
>      componentAttributes: {
>        recordId : component.get("v.recordId")
>      }
>    });
>    evt.fire();
> }
> ```

Comment: Tested, unfortunately this hides BOTH boxes. There doesn't seem to be any classes that are unique enough to hide only the desired box.